# Error SourceMaps: no sourcemap url found in generated script when using MSSQL in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, sql-server, source-maps

I am trying to extract data from SQL in Node.JS through Visual Studio 2017.

Here is the code:

```
var sql = require("mssql");

var dbConfig = {
    server: "my server",
    database: "data",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    port:1433
};

function getTestingDB() {
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
    var req = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        req.query("SELECT 1 FROM TestingDB", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log(recordset);
            }
            conn.close();
        });
    });
}
getTestingDB();
```

After debugging, I get these errors:

> **SourceMaps: expanded globs and found 1948 scripts SourceMaps: no sourcemap url found in generated script:**
>   c:\Users\user\Desktop\TestingDataBase\TestingDataBase\node_modules\babel-runtime\core-js\array\concat.js
>   **SourceMaps: no sourcemap url found in generated script:** c:\Users\user\Desktop\TestingDataBase\TestingDataBase\node_modules\babel-runtime\core-js.js

I had a look and the settings of chrome and it enables source maps.

I don't know what it is, if you have an idea let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I close this question due to I found the answer. 
I used mssql and install tedious 
Refer to this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-2017